# MS Access ACCDB : Corrupted Database "Id is not an index"

Tags: microsoft-access

I currently have an Front End Access Database with a corrupt VBA project. This DB doesn't store data, only Forms, Reports, Queries, Macros and Modules. The file format is **ACCDB**

When I open it, I get multiple **"Id is not an index in this table"** popups, then I get access to the Database.

However, whenever I want to open a Form/Report/Table in View mode, I get the "Id is not an index in this table" message again multiple times, then nothing happens.

The only way I've been able to see what was in "MSysCompactError" is by trying to export the Table to a Text File (The preview works, not the export). It contains 2 lines like the following :

`-1504;"You tried to assign Null to a variable that isn't a Variant";;"MSysAccessStorage"`

When I try to export my Forms/Reports to another Access Database, or try to import them from another DB, I still get the "Id is not an index in this table" message and I can't Import/Export.

My question is, how can I get it in a state when I can retreive the Forms/Reports/Queries ? Or, in a more general way, how can I retreive them ?

Comment: There's tons of info out there about dealing with that error ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883456/ms-access-id-is-not-a-valid-index)).  What have you attempted already?  Generally that error is because your DB is simply corrupted.  Assuming you have no backup, get what you can and recreate the broken parts from scratch.

Comment: That's why I asked. Even the multiple 3rd party tools I used couldn't restore anything. One of them could just restore the local tables, without their colum names. I'll have backups available tomorrow, but I was wondering if I missed a solution